# How to get data for a custom widget using an async source

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-signals

I'm new to QT and I would like some help. If any of you could help me I would really appreciate it.

**QUESTION:**

I have an asynchronous class that makes an HTTP request and it's going to receive some data into a JSON format and from there I will extract the necessary information which should be passed to my custom widget. How can I do that? Because I don't know when the information will arrive.

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR:**

My HTTP request and parsing JSON class:

```
WeatherAPI::WeatherAPI(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply * )), this, SLOT(readData(QNetworkReply * )));
}

void WeatherAPI::readData(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        QString strReply = (QString) reply->readAll();
        QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());
        QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();
        weatherObject.city = jsonObject["name"].toString();
        weatherObject.temperature = QString::number(jsonObject["main"].toObject()["temp"].toDouble() - 273.15);

        int ts = jsonObject["dt"].toInt();
        weatherObject.time = QDateTime::fromSecsSinceEpoch(ts).toString("hh:mm");
        auto weatherData = jsonObject["weather"].toArray()[0].toObject()["main"].toString();
        if (weatherData == "Clouds") {
            weatherObject.icon = "Sun.png";
        }
    } else {
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
    }
}

void WeatherAPI::requestDataForCity(const QString &city) {
    QString link = linkTemplate.arg(city, key);
    QUrl url(link);
    manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

const WeatherObject &WeatherAPI::getWeatherObject() const {
    return weatherObject;
}
```

Now here is my custom Widget:

```
void WeatherButton::initStyle(const QJsonValue &json) {
    PolygonButtonWidget::initStyle(json);
    auto cities = json.toObject()["cities"].toArray();
    api = new WeatherAPI(this); 
    for (auto c: cities) {
        QString city = c.toString();
        api->requestDataForCity(city); // HERE I'm making the http request
        WeatherObject data = api->getWeatherObject();//HERE I'm getting the DATA
        m_title = data.city;
        m_time = data.time;
        m_icon = data.icon;
        m_temperature = data.temperature;
    }
}
```

In that function from **WeatherButton::initStyle** I'm going to make an HTTP request and also I'm going to place the data into the necessary variable. Now my question is... How can I wait for that data to be received and just after that to place them into those variables?

So far the only solution I know so far is to use a **QEventLoop**, but at that moment I'm going to basically convert an async call into a sync one, which is not quite what I want. I want to be fully async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `WeatherObject data = api->getWeatherObject(); //HERE I'm getting the DATA`

No, you do not get the data here. `WeatherAPI::readData` is where you get the data.

That is the point of the [Signal - Slot mechanism](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). You do not wait for an event to happen, but react to it via callback, i.e. slot.

Having that in mind, you have to rethink and extend your code. Here is one way to do this:

1. In the `WeatherAPI` class define a `dataReady(const WeatherObject &weatherObject)` signal
2. Emit this signal in `WeatherAPI::readData` like this:

   ```
    void WeatherAPI::readData(QNetworkReply *reply) {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            // the processing of the http response remains unchanged
            // ...
            emit dataReady(weatherObject);
        } else {
            qDebug() << "ERROR";
        }
    }
   ```
3. In the `WeatherButton` class define a `onDataReady` slot with the following implementation:

   ```
    void WeatherButton::onDataReady(const WeatherObject &weatherObject) {
        m_title = weatherObject.city;
        m_time = weatherObject.time;
        m_icon = weatherObject.icon;
        m_temperature = weatherObject.temperature;
    }
   ```
4. Connect the newly created signal and slot in `WeatherButton::initStyle` like this:

   ```
    void WeatherButton::initStyle(const QJsonValue &json) {
        PolygonButtonWidget::initStyle(json);
        auto cities = json.toObject()["cities"].toArray();
        api = new WeatherAPI(this);
        connect(api, &WeatherAPI::dataReady, this, &WeatherButton::onDataReady);

        for (auto c: cities) {
            QString city = c.toString();
            api->requestDataForCity(city); // HERE I'm making the http request
        }
    }
   ```

As a sidenote I should say, that `initStyle` is probably not the best place to instantiate the `WeatherAPI`. `api` seems to be an attribute of `WeatherButton`, hence it should be initialized in the constructor of the class.